# Do translational invariance implies the conservation of both magnitude and direction of the corresponding momentum?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Suppose one is studying transmission in a system having translational invariance along $y$ direction. Should both direction and magnitude of $k_y$ ($y$ component of momentum of the wave) be necessarily same? Can a flip of sign of $k_y$ happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value, including direction/sign, is conserved. The Euler-Lagrange equation makes clear why such a momentum has zero time derivative. The Lagrangian doesn't depend on the spatial coordinate along which translation occurs; this coordinate is define is described as cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each translation direction implies conservation of momentum in the direction of the translation. Thus, each component of momentum is conserved separately because of the orthogonal translation directions. That each component of momentum is conserved separately implies that the direction and magnitude of momentum are conserved, because those quantities can be calculated from the components of the vector.